# not inject my config in core module in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this config file for my project:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<string>('app.config');
export interface IAppConfig {
    apiEndpoint: string;
    headersOptions: HttpHeaders;
}

export const AppConfig: IAppConfig = {
    apiEndpoint: 'https://localhost:44354/',
    headersOptions : new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
};
```

And I'm using `core.module`:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  ToastrModule.forRoot()
],
exports: [],
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_CONFIG,
    useValue: AppConfig
  },
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: RequestInterceptor, multi: true
  }
],
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() core: CoreModule) {
    if (core) {
      throw new Error("CoreModule should be imported ONLY in AppModule.");
    }
  }
}
```

And I use it in the `app.module` and do not inject it in the other module.

For exmaple, I use it in the `regster.module` for using in service:

```
constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject(AppConfig) private appConfig: IAppConfig) {
   super(httpClient);
}
```

But it shows me this error:

```
>Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[[object Object]]:
```

What's the problem and how can I sovle it?

Comment: Shouldn't there be `@Inject(APP_CONFIG)` instead of `@Inject(AppConfig)` ? `AppConfig` is the value, whereas `APP_CONFIG` is the provider.

Comment: Proper code indenting and general cleanup